# How do I set AppSettings in an ASPX project's Configuration manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

This is an ASPX/CS Project with Visual Studio 2010.  It is a Configuration Manager question.

I am successfully debugging (sort of) some code that is being used already on a server.  But there is a piece of code that plays with the URL in the live version that should not be used in the debug/localhost version.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsTesting"] == "false" && Request.Url.ToString().Contains("http:"))
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"));
        }

        LoadMasterTemplate();
    }
```

This piece of code lands on the "Response.Redirect...." line when it should not because the "IsTesting" app setting should be set to true in the ConfigurationManager .  How do I set that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `<configuration>` element in your App/Web.config file, there should be (or you should create) a `<appSettings></appSettings>` tag, and the individual settings look a bit like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="NewKey0" value="Something1" />
  <add key="NewKey1" value="Something2" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: You are correct.  I found in web.config file this:                      <add key="IsTesting" value="false" />

Answer (score 1):

"ConfigurationManager" looks at "Web.Config" for ASP.Net solutions, so you can find it either in:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="IsTesting" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>    
</configuration>
```

Or if you access the IIS Manager and select the website then click on "Application Settings" you can change it through a GUI.